# Implementing mbsnrtowcs in terms of mbsrtowcs

Tags: c++

In an almost complete effort to port libc++ to Windows, I need the function `mbsnrtowcs`, and thought that the easiest way would be to implement it in terms of `mbsrtowcs`:

```
size_t mbsnrtowcs( wchar_t *__restrict__ dst, const char **__restrict__ src,
               size_t nmc, size_t len, mbstate_t *__restrict__ ps )
{
    char* nmcsrc = new char[nmc+1];
    strncpy( nmcsrc, *src, nmc );
    nmcsrc[nmc] = '\0';
    const size_t result = mbsrtowcs( dst, &nmcsrc, len, ps );
    delete[] nmcsrc;
    return result;
}
```

The problem here is that `mbsrtowcs` needs `&nmcsrc` to be of type `const char**`, which is isn't, because it is a string I just copied the first `nmc` elements into, and appended a `\0` character to. How can I work around this? Strictly speaking, this is compiled as C++, so perhaps a `const_cast` would do little harm here? I also have access to c++0X (libc++ is/requires a subset c++0x).

Edit: the Clang error message reads:

```
M:\Development\Source\libc++\src\support\win32\support.cpp:37:27: error: no matching function for call to 'mbsrtowcs'
const size_t result = mbsrtowcs( dst, &nmcsrc, len, ps );
                      ^~~~~~~~~
M:/Development/mingw64/bin/../lib/clang/3.0/../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include\wchar.h:732:18: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char **' to 'const char **restrict' for 2nd argument;
  size_t __cdecl mbsrtowcs(wchar_t * __restrict__ _Dest,const char ** __restrict__ _PSrc,size_t _Count,mbstate_t * __restrict__ _State) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
                 ^
```

EDIT2: To fix what was wrong Re. Matthieu, I have changed my naive implementation like so:

```
size_t mbsnrtowcs( wchar_t *__restrict__ dst, const char **__restrict__ src,
                   size_t nmc, size_t len, mbstate_t *__restrict__ ps )
{
    char* local_src = new char[nmc+1];
    char* nmcsrc = local_src;
    strncpy( nmcsrc, *src, nmc );
    nmcsrc[nmc] = '\0';
    const size_t result = mbsrtowcs( dst, const_cast<const char **>(&nmcsrc), len, ps );
    // propagate error
    if( nmcsrc == NULL )
        *src = NULL;
    delete[] local_src;
    return result;
}
```

And I have added a FIXME saying that the proper way to do this would be implementing it via mbrtowc.

Comment: According to `man mbsrtowcs`, the signature of that function is `(wchar *, const char **, size_t, mbstate_t *)`. There's no `const wchar_t **` in there.

Comment: Kerrek: that's what I meant. I also need the `wchar_t` version, hence the typo. Fixed that in the question.

Comment: But then there's no problem, is there? You just want something *more* constant.

Comment: Kerrek: Clang thinks there is. Note that these functions are declared with `restrict` keywords...

Comment: There's no `restrict` in C++11 (nor in any C++). You're dealing with compiler extensions at best. E.g. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434549/does-c11-add-the-c99-restrict-specifier-if-not-why-not/6434582#6434582).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue here (not really related to the `const` I think).

`mbsrtowcs` might set `*src` to `NULL`.

`mbsnrtowcs` is supposed to do the same, of course.

However for you here it causes a 2 bugs:

- Because you created a local alias, if `mbsrtowcs` set `*src` to `NULL` it is not reflected for the caller of `mbsnrtowcs`
- `mbsnrtowcs` has a memory leak if `nmcsrc` is set to `NULL`

Perhaps that simply biting the bullet and implementing `mbsnrtowcs` in terms of `mbrtowc` would be more efficient ?

If you need to implement both (as I guess you do), you could also reverse the problem on its head and implement `mbsrtowcs` in terms of `mbsnrtowcs` simply by calling `strlen` at the beginning without loss of generality (and avoid the copy).

Comment: Good point; you actually need to implement the function logic correctly. Making a copy of `nmsrc` would be a start.

Comment: @Kerrek: Yes, make it correct, then make fast. Saving `nmsrc` to be sure to `delete` the allocated buffer and being able to check if it's been set to `NULL` would work. On a related note I still haven't found why C++ does not allow the `const` deduction here. I think Johannes provided a demo of how this could be abused, but I am not sure :/

Comment: I understand mine is a naive and bad implementation, but I really don't trust myself in these things to do otherwise. libc++ is opensource, so if you feel compelled ;)? I have updated my question with NULL handling. I think everything should be fine now? I hope I didn't mess up the pointer alias...

Comment: @MatthieuM: No idea if this would be a desirable extension, but at present you're trying to deduce `U*` from `T*`, which just isn't allowed - you can only deduce `const T` from `T`.

Comment: @rubenvb: I know, I've been watching your discussions with Howard on the list, awesome job by the way ;) I already have too many projects on my plate though :/

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem, since the function expects a *more restrictive* interface. So you can just cast the pointer:

```
const size_t result = std::mbsrtowcs(dst, const_cast<const char **>(&nmcsrc), len, ps);
```

I'm not sure about `restrict`; you may need to add that to the cast as well (not on GCC, though) - that's a compiler-dependent matter, though, as there is no `restrict` in C++.