# Initializing a char as 256

Tags: c++, char, ascii

My curiosity got the better of me.
What would happen (or does happen) when you write the code:

```
char pseudo_char = 256;
```

Would it store a virtual char with a value of 256? Or is this illegal and should never be done?

Comment: char is typically 0-255 (in most systems)

Comment: The Compiler can do what it wants.  I expect most modern ones issue a warning and initialise the char to Zero.

Comment: Or `[-128,+127]`. Don't assume either; there's `signed char` and `unsigned char` if you want to be explicit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's **probably** an overflow (unless `CHAR_MAX >= 256`). That's Undefined Behavior, and anything may happen. It's **unlikely** to format your harddisk.

Comment: `It's unlikely to format your harddisk.` I like that remark.

Comment: Interesting. And should CHAR_MAX ever be >=256? I would assume not.

Comment: @C_B: I'd expect it to be 32767 or 65535 when `CHAR_BIT==16`.

Comment: @C_B Some icky compilers use `char` as 16 bits when implementing a larger symbol table, instead of using `wchar_t` for such things.

Comment: @Lundin: That's rarely the reason. `char` is the smallest addressable object (i.e. sizeof(char)==1). On some DSPs, it's impossible to address 8 bits.

Comment: @MSalters Does the C standard actually mandate that char is the smallest addressable object?

Comment: @Lundin: Yes. Else you could create a pointer that you couldn't cast to `char*`, and that would e.g.. break `memcpy`.

Comment: @MSalters I believe that casting to and from char* is implementation-defined behavior, so if someone wanted to make some really weird implementation, there's probably room for it. I don't think there exists any text anywhere in the standard that mandates that a certain pointer type must be able to point at the smallest addressable object. I'm not sure, so if you are, please point of the relevant section of the standard.

Comment: @Lundin: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995748/when-and-how-is-conversion-to-char-pointer-allowed for all details including relevant sections.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an **[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**. The range of char is -128 to +127 or 0 to 255 based on if it is signed or unsigned, so anything may happen in your case.

> Would it store a virtual char with a value of 256?

It will show  you an undefined behavior. Something which you cant predict.

> Or is this illegal and should never be done?

I would not say that it is illegal but yes if you dont want to get into unpredictable environment then dont do this.

Comment: The range may actually be 0 to 255. It's implementation specific if a `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: Your assumed range is incorrect. It's at least `[0, 127]`, probably more, but you shouldn't assume how much more and in which direction.

Answer (score 1):

That would produce a warning saying "overflow occured". But I figured out that after 255 any other number assigned to the char - it restarts from 0 and assigns appropriate ASCII char to it.
Like

```
256 -> (null) equivalent to 0

300 = 256+44 -> , equivalent to 44
```

Comment: Very interesting, nice touch.

Comment: Note that this a compiler-specific answer, but fails to state which compiler. And on some compilers it even depends on settings (e.g. in Visual Studio 400->144 OR -112)

Comment: I would like to know whether this is machine dependant or something? Is is that LSB is discared by compiler after reaching 255 limit?

Comment: Most likely the compiler will indeed implement integer overflow like this, but there are no guarantees. Simply because the C standard decided: "Oh no, overflow! Lets panic and make this undefined behavior.". Even though there is actually no reason why they couldn't have made it well-defined. It's related to the retarded way the C standard allows different forms of signed number formats, other than two's complement.

Comment: @Lundin: ANd how would you implement two's complement efficiently on a CPU that does one's complement or has an explicit sign bit. If you think those are theoretical, the Cray supercomputers had sign bits.

Comment: @MSalters That's the problem, the C standard is an ISO standard so they aren't allowed to favour certain architectures and thereby give them a market advantage. But if they simply had defined signed numbers to always be two's complement and those obscure, experimental computers be damned, then C would have been a far better programming language.

Comment: @Lundin: nonsense, the C rules predate ISO by about a decade. Also, ISO standards may certainly favor certain architectures. For example, C favors machines with a stack.

Comment: @MSalters Well, that's what I heard from someone who was actually on the C99 committee.

Comment: @Lundin: You probably misunderstood. I was a member of WG21, not WG14, but they operate under the same ISO rules. Both work on a consensus model, and for that reason generally do not favor specific architectures. It got really complicated with the memory models for multi-threading, where it's trivial to accidentally favor an architecture.