# c++ - type punning from an unsigned char pointer when the underlying type is known

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing, type-punning

Does the following program invoke any undefined behavior? In particular, does it break any strict aliasing rules?

```
void zeroInt(unsigned char *mem) {
    *reinterpret_cast<int *>(mem) = 0;
}

int main() {
    int value;
    zeroInt(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&value));
    return value;
}
```

I compiled it with gcc using `-O2 -Wstrict-aliasing=3` and it didn't complain, however the gcc docs say that it doesn't catch all cases.

Comment: It looks fine. The various `char` types are allowed to alias other objects.

Comment: related/dupe/good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995748/when-and-how-is-conversion-to-char-pointer-allowed

Comment: Note that, since the only thing you do with the reinterpreted pointer is to reinterpret back to the original type, you have a lot more guarantees on behavior.

Comment: @KerrekSB So am I allowed to cast back from a char type pointer to the original pointer, assuming I know what the original type is?

Comment: Absolutely no aliasing whatsoever is happening in your code. You are allowed to cast a pointer to a pointer to a character type and back to the original type. This is not aliasing. Aliasing is when you cast a pointer to a pointer of another type *and then dereference that other pointer*.

Comment: @user1000039: As n.m. says, you're not aliasing anything. Your only concern is whether `char*` is suitable for round-tripping other object pointers (which it is, cf. [basic.compound]p5). But even aliasing would be OK, i.e. *accessing* the char array elements.

Comment: This is not "type punning". Every case of type punning must be somewhat dependent on the representation of values.