# Do the strict aliasing rules in C++20 allow `reinterpret_cast` between the standard c++ unicode chars and the underlining types?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing, c++20

Do the `C++20`'s ***strict aliasing rules*** [[basic.lval]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#basic.lval-11) arbitrarily allow following...

1. cast between `char*` and `char8_t*`

```
string str = "string";
u8string u8str { (char8_t*) &*str.data() }; // c++20 u8string

u8string u8str2 = u8"zß水"
string str2 { (char*) u8str2.data() };
```

2. cast between `uint32_t*`, `uint_least32_t*` and `char32_t*`

```
vector<uint32_t> ui32vec = { 0x007a, 0x00df, 0x6c34, 0x0001f34c };
u32string u32str { (char32_t*) &*ui32vec.data(), ui32vec.size() };

u32string u32str2 = U"zß水"
vector<uint32_t> ui32vec2 { (uint32_t*) &*u32str2.begin(),
                            (uint32_t*) &*u32str2.end() };
```

3. cast between `uint16_t*`, `uint_least16_t*` and `char16_t*`

```
vector<uint16_t> ui16vec = { 0x007a, 0x00df, 0x6c34, 0xd83c, 0xdf4c };
u16string u16str { (char16_t*) &*ui16vec.data(), ui16vec.size() };

u16string u16str2 = u"zß水\ud83c\udf4c"
vector<uint16_t> ui16vec2 { (uint16_t*) &*u16str2.begin(),
                            (uint16_t*) &*u16str2.end() };
```

---

### Update

basic_string contructor [overload (6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

```
template< class InputIt >    
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

vector constuctor [overload (4)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
template< class InputIt >    
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

I wonder whether it is okey to go with ***LegacyInputIterator*** constructors?...

4. `char*` and `char8_t*` as *LegacyInputIterator*

```
string str = "string";
u8string u8str {   str.begin(),   str.end()  };
u8string u8str { &*str.begin(), &*str.end()  };

u8string u8str2 = u8"zß水"
string str2 {   u8str2.begin(),   u8str2.end() };
string str2 { &*u8str2.begin(), &*u8str2.end() };
```

5. `uint32_t*`, `uint_least32_t*` and `char32_t*` as *LegacyInputIterator*

```
vector<uint32_t> ui32vec = { 0x007a, 0x00df, 0x6c34, 0x0001f34c };
u32string u32str {   ui32vec.begin(),   ui32vec.end() };
u32string u32str { &*ui32vec.begin(), &*ui32vec.end() };

u32string u32str2 = U"zß水"
vector<uint32_t> ui32vec2 { u32str2.begin(),
                            u32str2.end() };
vector<uint32_t> ui32vec2 { &*u32str2.begin(),
                            &*u32str2.end() };
```

6. `uint16_t*`, `uint_least16_t*` and `char16_t*` as *LegacyInputIterator*

```
vector<uint16_t> ui16vec = { 0x007a, 0x00df, 0x6c34, 0xd83c, 0xdf4c };
u16string u16str {   ui16vec.begin(),   ui16vec.end() };
u16string u16str { &*ui16vec.begin(), &*ui16vec.end() };

u16string u16str2 = u"zß水\ud83c\udf4c"
vector<uint16_t> ui16vec2 { u16str2.begin(),
                            u16str2.end() };
vector<uint16_t> ui16vec2 { &*u16str2.begin(),
                            &*u16str2.end() };
```

Comment: @curiousguy: They are not typedefs. They are distinct types (which do have underlying types).

Comment: @curiousguy: It depends on what "these" you're talking about. Since the question was pretty focused on the `char*_t`, I assumed that's what you were talking about. Those are not typedefs, and cplusplus.com doesn't say that they are.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm sorry for the confusion. I meant *those identifiers in the Q which are `typedef`* (`uint32_t`, `uint_least32_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint_least16_t`); it depends which type they represent.

Answer (score 9):

The `char*_t` line of types do not have any special aliasing rules. Therefore, the [standard rules apply](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#11). And those rules do not have exceptions for conversion between underlying types.

So most of what you did is UB. The one case that isn't UB is `char` due to its special nature. You can in fact read the bytes of a `char8_t` as an array of `char`. But you can't do the opposite, reading the bytes of a `char` array as `char8_t`.

Now, these types *are* completely convertible to each other. So you can convert the values in those array to the other type anytime you want.

All that being said, on real implementations those things will almost certainly work. Well, until they don't, because you tried to change one thing through a thing that it's not supposed to be changed by, and the compiler doesn't reload the changed value because it assumed that it couldn't have been changed. So really, just use the correct, meaningful type.

Answer (score 2):

Just so we are on the same page, the C-style casts of `(T*) expression` are equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<T*>(expression)` ([[expr.cast]/4.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4.4)), which is equivalent to `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(expression))` ([[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7)). This does nothing to the value of the pointer, as they are not pointer-interconvertible. (See [[expr.static.cast]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13) and [[basic.compound]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4)).

So yes, we would have to look at [[basic.lval]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11) to see if it can be aliased. The reference must have a type which is similar to:

> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> - a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte` type.

Which is not the case. Even though `char8_t` has the underlying type of `unsigned char`, it is not a similar type.

So, for example:

```
unsigned char uc = 'a';

// Represents address of uc
unsigned char* uc_ptr = &uc;

// Still holds the address of uc, not a char8_t
char8_t* c8_ptr = reinterpret_cast<char8_t*>(uc_ptr);

char8_t c8 = *c8_ptr;  // UB, as `char8_t` is not `cv unsigned char`.
```

Though because of [[basic.fundamentals]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#6), which says:

> A fundamental type specified to have a signed or unsigned integer type as its underlying type has the same object representation [...]

You *can* do `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pointer-to-char8_t)` and have all the values be equal, but that is the only case (And also `char*` if `char` is unsigned or none of the values have their sign bit set). For all other types, you can use this rule to `memcpy`:

```
// Assuming std::is_same_v<uint32_t, uint_least32_t>
vector<uint32_t> ui32vec = { 0x007a, 0x00df, 0x6c34, 0x0001f34c };
u32string u32str(ui32vec.size(), U'\x00');
std::memcpy(u32str.data(), ui32vec.data(), ui32vec.size() * sizeof(uint32_t));

u32string u32str2 = U"zß水"
vector<uint32_t> ui32vec2(u32str2.size(), U'\x00');
std::memcpy(u32str2.data(), ui32vec2.data(), u32str2.size() * sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Comment: So `Iter` ctor or `memcpy` are only options because the strict alias are so strict that do not allow even `underlining type` : `unsigned char`, `uint_least32_t`, `uint_least16_t`?

Comment: @sandthorn Yes. If you are specifically using `vector` and `string`, `std::memcpy` is by far the best option, as you would have to copy anyways ([And at g++ `memcpy`s if you `reinterpret_cast`, so it is the same thing](https://godbolt.org/z/rSXTLN)). If you are using a non-owning container, like `std::string_view`, you cannot reinterpret.

Comment: Dang it. `Iter` ctor of `string` is not allow neither, because in `LegacyInputIterator` the `value_type` is un-interchangeable between any CharT and its underlining type anyway.

Comment: @sandthorn The `Iter` ctor should work, as [the iterators value type only needs to be implicitly convertible](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#sequence.reqmts-3), and `char32_t` and `uint_least32_t` are implicitly convertible.

Comment: How about `char8_t` and its underlining `unsigned char`, are they also implicitly convertible?

Comment: @sandthorn Yes. `char*_t`, `(un)signed char`, `uint*_t` and `uint_*_t` are all integral types, which are all implicitly convertible to each other.

Comment: @sandthorn: Convertible is a different question from whether casting from one to the other will work.

Comment: @NicolBolas By using ***LegacyInputIterator*** ctor in vector and string, does it mean that I can just do the `someStringOrVector { src.begin(), src.end() }` because it only requires `is_convertible_v` so that `value_type = *Iter` is valid, right?

Comment: @sandthorn Yes, but it is slower as it calls all it does it through a generic iterator instead of a pointer. See [the second row of the sequence container requirements table](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.sequence.requirements)

Answer (score 1):

C-style cast is not the same thing as `reinterpret_cast`.

The standard sections I think are relevant to your question:

> [6.7.1.9](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#9): Type char8_­t denotes a distinct type whose underlying type is unsigned char. Types char16_­t and char32_­t denote distinct types whose underlying types are uint_­least16_­t and uint_­least32_­t, respectively, in .
>
> [7.2.1.11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#basic.lval-11.3):  If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar ([conv.qual]) to one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> 1.
>   the dynamic type of the object,
>
> 2.
>   a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
>
> 3.
>   a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.

1. `char8_t*-->char*` **Yes.**
   Because `char` is one of the types that
   all objects can be   converted to. But the standard does not guarantee that the (dereferenced) converted values are equal for distinct types. `char` can be signed or not and `char8_t` is unsigned. `char8_t*-->unsigned char*` is valid but should not guarantee that either because it's still distinct. But given that it's `char8_t`'s underlying type it should be, I guess?
2. `char*-->char8_t*` **No**.
   As per 6.7.1.9 those types are distinct. Although there might be argument made that "**whose underlying type is unsigned char**" part could apply with `unsigned char` being explicitly allowed in 7.2.1.11.3 but I don't think that would be the correct interpretation and being distinct should be the deciding factor. That is supported by the following quote of a comment in the proposal [P0482R6 - char8_t: A type for UTF-8 characters and strings (Revision 6 - 2018-11-09)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0482r6.html)  (I did not find more recent revision):

   > Finally, processing of UTF-8 strings is currently subject to an optimization pessimization due to glvalue expressions of type char potentially aliasing objects of other types. Use of a distinct type that does not share this aliasing behavior may allow for further compiler optimizations.
3. `uint32_t*<-->char32_t*`, `uint16_t*<-->char16_t*`, `uint16_t*<-->uint_least16_t*`, `uint32_t*<-->uint_least32_t*`, `uint_least32_t<-->char32_t`, `uint_least16_t<-->char16_t`: **No**.
   Those pairs are all distinct, so 7.2.1.11.1 does not apply and neither type is in 7.2.1.11.3 so not even the second part of 2. can be relevant.
4. `unsigned char*-->char8_t*` **No**.
   By the same argument as in 2. It's not `T*->T*` cast which is obviously allowed.
5. `char8_t*-->unsigned char*` **Yes**.
   Because `unsigned char` is too one of the allowed types per 7.2.1.11.3 . But I would still argue that the standard does not guarantee that the (dereferenced) converted values will equal. But given that it's char8_t's underlying type it doesn't have any other options  other than to be equal, I guess?

Comment: `unsigned char <-->char8_t`, `uint_least16_t<-->char16_t`, `uint_least32_t<-->char32_t` : Would you mind adding these contexts in above answer?

Comment: @sandthorn Sure, give me a moment.

Comment: @sandthorn There, except `char8_t -> unsigned char` are all Nos. I added them to 3.