# libstdc++ deprecation message for u8path suggests a strict aliasing violation as a workaround?

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

C++20 deprecates `std::filesystem::u8path`:

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:6),source:%27%23include+%3Cfilesystem%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+path+%3D+std::filesystem::u8path(%22/%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B23+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-Wdeprecated%27,overrides:!(),paneName:GCC,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:GCC,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,paneName:%27GCC+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27GCC+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <filesystem>

std::string foo();

int main()
{
    auto path = std::filesystem::u8path(foo());
}
```

libstdc++ 13 has a deprecation warning in place:

```
<source>:7:40: warning: 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path std::filesystem::__cxx11::u8path(
const _Source&) [with _Source = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Require = path; _CharT
 = char]' is deprecated: use 'path((const char8_t*)&*source)' instead [-Wdeprecated-decla
rations]
    7 |     auto path = std::filesystem::u8path(foo());
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

The proposed cast `path((const char8_t*)&*source)` looks like an outright strict aliasing violation to me, and hence UB.

Is that correct? Is GCC making any additional guarantees that make this legal?

And lastly, is there a better workaround if my path is stored in `std::string` and I don't want to rewrite everything to `std::u8string`?

Comment: Why not use `std::filesystem::path`?

Comment: True valid code seems to be like `const auto& s = foo(); std::filesystem::path({s.begin(), s.end()});`. See about UB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415276/do-the-strict-aliasing-rules-in-c20-allow-reinterpret-cast-between-the-stand

Comment: @273K *"Why not use std::filesystem::path"* It's annoying to deal with. I don't like it using wide strings on Windows. Converting to and from narrow non-u8 strings on MSVC STL throws on unicode paths, unless you set an unicode-aware locale (or use a function like `u8path`), which is dumb. `{s.begin(), s.end()}` allocates a copy of the string on the heap, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: If you have a `std::string` and want a `std::filesystem::u8path`, you'll need to do a conversion from plain string to UTF-8 _somewhere_.  And C++ has deprecated all the character-coding conversions, with no Standard Library replacement, so you'll need a third-party library such as ICU. Or hand-roll some conversions.

Comment: @TobySpeight My `std::string` is already UTF8. I guess I could hand-roll the conversion to UTF16, but I'd rather not.

Comment: The alternative (and the one I'm sticking with for now) is to continue using the deprecated conversion functions until they are actually removed from C++.  I have a tiny shim header that wraps the functions I use, which avoids warning spam (I can suppress the deprecation warning in that file) and gives somewhere to plumb in the replacement in the future when it's needed.

Comment: dealing with UTF16 paths via UTF8(or even worse latin1) makes program unportable though. Most common case of breach is acually your native locale (same as mine, I had  lots of grief so I use third-party libraries - ICU to deal with strings or  Qt, whcih already uses ICU.

Comment: @TobySpeight Mhm, I guess I'm going to do the same.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie *"makes program unportable though"* Why? Do you mean assuming that narrow non-u8 strings are UTF8 is non-portable? Seemed to work well enough after setting a UTF8 locale on MSVC STL. libstdc++ and libc++ seem to assume UTF8 even without the locale.

Comment: becuase conversions between wchar and utf-8 are unportable and windows got own version of whcar for FS locales. Russian is marginally striken by that (console only becuase console on windows is NOT unicode..it's DOS 866 page by defalt), some asian locales even worse. Not to mention on wire with some protocols where their encoding uses  ISO\ANSI EOT character code as a letter and have non-standard EOT.. 255 being a printable letter in many 8-bit pages on Windows was partially a reason why they rolled out wchar.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Are you confusing UTF8 and narrow characters in general? wchar_t<->UTF8 should be portable enough, it's wchar_t<->char that's not portable (but is fixed by setting a custom locale). As long as I'm using either the locale **or** `u8path` (or functions operating on `char8_t` as opposed to `char`), I should be fine.

Comment: Why not use char8_t throughout? And what's wrong with using the locale? That's what most programs do anyway.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI *"char8_t throughout"* I guess I could, but that means unlearning my muscle memory of using `char` and `std::string`. *"locale"* I guess I can, but it's moderately annoying when I've had a locale-free way of doing it before. And that probably would be a bad idea when making a library...

Comment: "I've had a locale-free way of doing it before." Me too, back when the world was ASCII. Not anymore. Get used to it. Setting a locale is a hard requirement for any serious program.

Comment: A library that is supposed to run on Windows should  work with wchar_t strings anyway, otherwise it won't get used by anyone but a bunch of hardcore UTF-8 aficionados.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI If my paths are always UTF8, I can still convert them to a wide strings without messing with the locale. *"hard requirement for any serious program"* I'd rather say doing l10n is a hard requirement. Wouldn't want to use the locale mechanism for that. (How do you even convert text to a number with a custom locale, if it happens to have `,` as decimal separator, and your text format uses `.`? New standards have `from_chars`, but before that? Can I be sure that all libraries I use do this the right way, and won't suddenly break on that locale?)

Comment: *"should work with wchar_t strings anyway"* Probably just both wchar_t and char strings (the latter assuming UTF8).

Comment: "Wouldn't want to use the locale mechanism for that" There is no standard alternative. But yes locales are pretty broken.

Answer (score 2):

In short, there is undefined behavior in your example. However, the actual cause is not a strict aliasing violation, but a precondition violation because of a hypothetical strict aliasing violation.

#### No undefined behavior due to strict aliasing

There is no strict aliasing violation ([[basic.lval] p11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)) because any access of the characters would happen within the constructor of `std::filesystem::path` or other parts of the filesystem library, and those could be permitted to type-pun in ways that the user can't.

`(const char8_t*)&*` is essentially a `reinterpret_cast<const char8_t*>` of your data.
`reinterpret_cast` on its own is valid, even if accessing objects through the pointer wouldn't be. With the resulting pointer, you would call the following constructor:

> ```cpp
> template<class Source>
> path(const Source& source, format fmt = auto_format);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Let `s` be the [effective range](https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.path.req) of source or the range `[first, last)`, with the [encoding converted](https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.path.type.cvt) if required.
> Finds the [detected-format](https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.path.fmt.cvt#def:detected-format) of `s` and constructs an object of class path for which the pathname in that format is `s`.

- [[fs.class.path] `std::path` constructor 3](https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.class.path#lib:path,constructor__)

The format detection, argument format conversions, and type and encoding conversions for the `path` are all defined mathematically or through prose. For example, the encoding conversion is defined in [[fs.path.type.cvt] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.path.type.cvt#2.3):

> For member function arguments that take character sequences representing paths and for member functions returning strings, [value type](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#def:value_type) and encoding conversion is performed if the [value type](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#def:value_type) of the argument or return value differs from `path​::​value_type`.
> For the argument or return value, the method of conversion and the encoding to be converted to is determined by its [value type](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#def:value_type):
>
> - [...]
> - `char8_t`: The encoding is UTF-8.
>   **The method of conversion is unspecified.**

The implementation has a lot of freedom when it comes to implementing this. The `std::filesystem::path` constructor could have relaxed aliasing rules for instance.

#### Undefined behavior due to precondition violation

The issue lies in the use of [value type](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#def:value_type):

> An input iterator `i` supports the expression `*i`, resulting in a value of some object type `T`, called the *value type* of the iterator.

Your iterator would be of type `const char8_t*`, and indirection (`*i`) would not be valid for it because it would hypothetically violate strict aliasing.
**Therefore, what you're passing to the `path` constructor has no [value type](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#def:value_type), and the behavior is undefined because of a precondition violation.**

#### GCC strict aliasing relaxations between character types

I was unable to find details about this in the GCC documentation, but `char8_t` appears to be able to alias `char`:

```cpp
auto alias(char c) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<char8_t*>(&c); // OK, no -Wstrict-aliasing
}
```

*See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fM79hbq6E).*

Presumably, you are thus relying on compiler extensions.

Comment: The apparent GCC aliasing exception is a shame. We could've had strings without aliasing issues, but alas. I wonder what Clang thinks about this.

Comment: Hmm.. what about `byte`?

Comment: GCC thinks that anything can alias char.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [P0482 (char8_t: A type for UTF-8 characters and strings)](https://wg21.link/p0482) proposal that deprecated `std::filesystem::u8path()` in C++20.

The recommendation offered by the libstdc++ warning is fine. Normally such casts are problematic, but `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte` are granted special powers to alias other types. This is courtesy of [[basic.lval]p11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11) that states:

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar to one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> - **a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std​::​byte` type.**
>
> ...

However, aliasing casts are to be avoided whenever possible and I recommend a different solution. `std::filesystem::path` has a constructor template that accepts a classic range (an iterator pair) and deduces encoding based on the value type of the range. For UTF-8 input that is held in `char`-based storage, all that is needed is a range adapter to convert the `char`-based values to `char8_t`. This can be performed with no run-time overhead:

```cpp
std::string utf8_encoded_filename = ...;
auto char8_view =
    std::ranges::views::transform(utf8_encoded_filename,
                                  [](char c) { return (char8_t)c; });
std::filesystem::path p(char8_view.begin(), char8_view.end());
```

Such a view adapter is sufficiently useful that a family of `charN_t` view adapters is being considered for standardization in [P2728 (Unicode in the Library, Part 1: UTF Transcoding)](https://wg21.link/p2728) (revision 6 at the time of this writing).

If desired, such a view adapter may be employed to provide a `u8path()` replacement that, again, poses no run-time overhead.

```cpp
template<std::ranges::viewable_range R>
requires std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, char>
constexpr auto as_char8_t(R &&r) {
  return std::ranges::views::transform(std::forward<R>(r),
                                       [](char c) { return (char8_t)c; });
}
std::filesystem::path u8path(const std::string &s) {
  auto char8_view = as_char8_t(s);
  return std::filesystem::path(char8_view.begin(), char8_view.end());
}
```

If you've read to this point, you are probably now wondering why `u8path` was deprecated if there are demonstrable use cases for it. Unfortunately, the original proposal lacks much defense of the deprecation. The motivation was that, prior to deprecation, there were only two interfaces in the standard library that required `char`-based input that held UTF-8 data; all other interfaces expect `char`-based input to hold text data encoded in the ordinary literal encoding used for character and string literals or in the execution encoding. Those two interfaces were:

- `std::filesystem::u8path()`
- `std::codecvt_utf8` (deprecated by [P0618 (Deprecating <codecvt>)](https://wg21.link/p0618))

The ordinary literal encoding and the execution encoding are not UTF-8 in practice for some popular (and some not-so-popular) implementations and this is expected to remain true for the foreseeable future. It is challenging to properly use and maintain text stored in multiple encodings without support from the type system and mistakes lead to quality and security issues. It was seen as important that the standard not encourage further use of `char` with UTF-8 encoded text; at least, not for portable code and there was concern about the potential to have to add `u8`-prefixed version of potentially many interfaces in the future. The inability to use the type system to overload based on encoding would have been an impediment for the development of generic code libraries.

Note: For backward compatibility with existing code that passes a `u8""` string literal to `std::filesystem::u8path()`, though deprecated, `std::filesystem::u8path()` was modified via [P1423 (char8_t backward compatibility remediation)](https://wg21.link/p1423) to accept a range of `char8_t`.

Comment: *"char, unsigned char, and std::byte are granted special powers"* Not `char8_t` though, so aliasing in this direction is still UB.

Comment: I just tested your `ranges::transform` approach, and while it does compile on the big 3 compilers, it does seem to have runtime overhead on all of them, at least from looking at the size of the assembly: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T4Yhj65Tq

Comment: You are correct that using `char8_t` to alias values of other types (including `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte`) is UB.

That comparison isn't really valid. In one case, the generated assembly is calling the non-inlined `std::filesystem::u8path()` function and in the other case, the invocation of the `std::filesystem::path` constructor is inlined leaving just a call to an internal `_Convert_range_to_wide()` implementation function.