# Does using unique_ptr mean that I don't have to use the restrict keyword?

Tags: c++11, vectorization

When trying to get loops to auto-vectorise, I've seen code like this written:

```
void addFP(int N, float *in1, float *in2, float * restrict out)
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < N; i++)
    {
         out[i] = in1[i] + in2[i];
    }
}
```

Where the restrict keyword is needed reassure the compiler about pointer aliases, so that it can vectorise the loop.

Would something like this do the same thing?

```
void addFP(int N, float *in1, float *in2, std::unique_ptr<float> out)
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < N; i++)
    {
         out[i] = in1[i] + in2[i];
    }
}
```

If this does work, which is the more portable choice?

tl;dr Can std::unique_ptr be used to replace the restrict keyword in a loop you're trying to auto-vectorise?

Comment: `unique_ptr<float>` points to a single `float`. (I think you can do `unique_ptr<float[]>` instead)

Answer (score 2):

[`restrict` is not part of C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434549/does-c11-add-the-c99-restrict-specifier-if-not-why-not), instead it is part of C99.

`std::unique_ptr<T> foo;` is telling your compiler: I only need the memory in this scope. Once this scope ends, free the memory.

`restrict` tells your compiler: I know that you can't know or proof this, but I pinky swear that this is the **only** reference to this chunk of memory that occurs in this function.

`unique_ptr` doesn't stop aliases, nor should the compiler assume they don't exist:

```
int* pointer = new int[3];
int* alias = pointer;

std::unique_ptr<int> alias2(pointer);
std::unique_ptr<int> alias3(pointer); //compiles, but crashes when deleting
```

So your first version is not valid in C++11 (though it works on many modern compilers) and the second doesn't do the optimization you are expecting. To still get the behavior concider [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Suppose this code:

```
auto p = std::make_unique<float>(0.1f);
auto raw = p.get();
addFP(1, raw, raw, std::move(p));
```

Comment: You can do this with `restrict` pointers as well, it’s just not defined what you’ll get.

Comment: @JonPurdy Doing this with `restrict` causes undefined behavior, which means that this is virtually forbidden by standard (think about `printf("%s", 42);`). In contrast, my answer's code doesn't and shouldn't make any errors (as far as I know)