# Do C89 or C++03 define strict aliasing rules?

Tags: c++, c

I've seen [several assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320789/c-aliasing-rules/6320834#6320834) that C89 and C++03 define strict aliasing rules. I, however, cannot find that particular bit in the standard. My understanding was that strict aliasing rules were added in C99.

Comment: I cited the entirety of C++03 3.10/15, which lists the valid forms of aliasing, [in an answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807643/container-covariance-in-c/4807726#4807726).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++03 standard has the following under `§3.10 [basic.lval] p15`:

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through an lvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined<sup>48)</sup>:
>   — the dynamic type of the object,
>   — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>   — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union),
>   — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
>   — a char or unsigned char type.

Footnote:

> <sup>48)</sup> The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.

[This site](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html) also lists the sections in the other standards.

Comment: Checking this because I explicitly picked on your answer in the question.

Answer (score 7):

This text is present in C89, §3.3 EXPRESSIONS:

> An object shall have its stored
>   value accessed only by an lvalue that
>   has one of the following types:
>
> - the declared type of the object,
> - a qualified version of the declared
>     type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or
>     unsigned type corresponding to the
>     declared type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or
>     unsigned type corresponding to a
>     qualified version of the declared type
>     of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that
>     includes one of the aforementioned
>     types among its members (including,
>     recursively, a member of a
>     subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

Violation of a "shall" constraint leads to undefined behaviour, so a set of allowed aliasing rules can be derived from this text.

Answer (score 6):

3.3 in C89, 3.10/15 in C++03.

Both have a footnote, words to the effect of, "the intent of this list is to indicate when an object may or may not be aliased".