# Pointers typecast

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, void-pointers

I have the followig code and I want to know why I have the following output:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double nValue = 5;
    void *pVoid = &nValue;

    short *pInt = static_cast<short*>(pVoid);

    std::cout << *pInt << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

And it outputs me '0'. I want to know why is this happening. Thank you!

Comment: C lets you break the rules and you get weird stuff. Its only predictable what happens on a given compiler and hardware and maybe not even then. Depends. It lets you break the rules because of a philosophy that says you might know what you are doing and so it gives you plenty of rope with which to hang yourself.

Comment: My question would be, what were you expecting the output to be?  `5`??

Answer (score 1):

You have UB (Undefined Behaviour), as you're violating pointer aliasing rules. This means anything can happen.

For example, the compiler has all rights to expect a `short*` will never refer to a `double` object, so it can pretty much interpret `*pInt` however it wants.

Or it's possible that the compiler interprets the code literally, and it just so happens that on your platform, the binary representation of `5.0` starts with two (or `sizeof(short)`) bytes of zeroes.

Comment: I would say that it is implementation defined undefined behavior

Comment: When I saw the output, I though at you second explanation and firstly I though it is the only explanation, but apparently it's not. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are casting memory block with `double` data to `short`. Since you store a small value in that block it is not stored in first bits. Thus first `bits` are zero. But it rely on internal `double` representation and `short` size, so it is not guaranteed to be the same on different platforms

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to interpret the contents of a `double` as a `short`. This invokes undefined behavior - your program is free to do anything.

Comment: You are correct, but I don't think the behavior is undefined. It interprets the bits in the memory as a short, no matter what. Which happens to be zero in this case. Undefined behaviour is typically when the programming standard etc doesent speciy what is going to happen.

Comment: @HenrikKjusAlstad And here, does it?

Comment: I'm not sure, you might be right. But the void pointer really just point at a memory address. Casting a void pointer to a short just tells the compiler to interpret whatever is there as a short. I don't see any reason why it should be undefined. Although I might be wrong

Comment: @HenrikKjusAlstad [There are alignment and aliasing rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320789/c-aliasing-rules).

Answer (score 0):

`pVoid` points to a bit pattern that represents a `double`. The type information is lost for the compiler once you use a `void*`. When casting the `void*` to `short*`, you claim that that the bit pattern pointed to is a `short`, which it isn't. The representation of a `short` and a `double` in memory are completely different. When you dereference `pInt`, the memory at that location happens to be 0. The compiler no longer knows at this point that the value's type is really `double`, so no implicit conversion is possible, if that's what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, most probably the double representation of 5 on your machine is this

```
                *double  = (5)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   *short = (0)
```

---

This should show you why this is happeneing

```
int main() {
    double nValue = 5;
    short nValue_short = 5;

    std::bitset<sizeof(double)*8> bit_double(nValue);
    std::bitset<sizeof(short)*8> bit_short(nValue_short);

    std::cout << bit_double << std::endl; 
    std::cout << bit_short << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It this have to do with my architecture ? I mean, if my architecture were Big Endian instead of Little Endian, the output would've been also 5 ?

Comment: That is of course not AT ALL what a double of value 5.0 actually looks like. And no, you would not get 5 no matter what endianness the system has - but on a little endian machine, we can expect the lower value bits of a small integer value to be a lot of zeros. [Lower value bits will be first on a little endian machine, and last on a big endian machine].